# Obfuscate single non-modular javascript file with require.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, minify

I have a project for which I'm using require.js to minify/obfuscate/combine some modules. I also have a single javascript file(7 lines of code) which I want to obfuscate in the same way but it's not organised as modules(7 lines of independent code doesn't justify the overhead of the require.js bootstrap code).

Is it possible to minify/obfuscate a single file using require.js?

---

edit: command that I'm already using to compile the rest of the code in the project:

```
node lib/r.js -o name=lib/almond.js include=src/main,requireLib out=extension-min.js baseUrl=./ paths.requireLib=lib/require
```

Comment: Not sure about require.js, but why not just use [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for that file?

Comment: That or the google compiler

Comment: r.js uses uglify already, so you can configure that to suit your needs.

Comment: @Simon Smith I can't find a way to use r.js if my code isn't modular, is there an way of using the uglify.js that is included with require.js?

Answer (score 0):

r.js uses uglify2 by default but if you want to make sure you can set `optimize='uglify2'`